# How to get top value in Postgres when ties?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

Everywhere people select top value using ORDER BY and LIMIT. But how to deal a scenario where the last element has duplicate entries.

Consider a 5 row table

| name | number_of_cookies |
| --- | --- |
| matt | 32 |
| Greg | 77 |
| vance | 21 |
| chen | 20 |
| louise | 77 |

Now I want the person with most number of cookies. If you query like this

```
select * from table ORDER BY number_of_cookies DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This will get only one person either Louise or greg. But here the answer is both people have most number of cookies. How to deal with these kind of scenario in Postgres when using LIMIT?

Also if I extend this question further and if I want to list top 10 values, and a situation like this(ties) exist then how I can deal with it ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  'only' and 'with ties' are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an SQL standard way to do this.  It doesn't use the LIMIT keyword, but rather FETCH

```
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

But support for the WITH TIES part of the standard wasn't added to PostgreSQL until v13.

Comment: thats exactly what I am looking for. used something similar in oracle.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY number_of_cookies DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT name, number_of_cookies
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: How can I extend this to say top 10 people with most cookies ?

Comment: Replace `RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER` and then restrict in the outer query to row number values which are 10 or less.  Note that in the case of ties, you might want slightly different logic.

Comment: exactly I am looking for the situation of ties. You got the right word.

Comment: If you want the top 10 performers, including ties, then use my answer with `DENSE_RANK`, and then restrain to the top 10 ranks in the outet query.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like that:

```
select * from table 
where number_of_cookies = (select max(number_of_cookies) from table)
```

this will return all names with maximal number

Comment: was looking for something straight forward like this. but can I extend this to say for top N people with number of cookies ?

Comment: it is better to use `rank()` like in Tim's answer, but you can also try `select * from table 
where number_of_cookies in (select distinct number_of_cookies from table order by number_of_cookies desc limit 10)`

Comment: This looks pretty straighforward. Look like this takes care of ties as well.